# Morphia query with $elemMatch and $eq

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this BSON query

```
{
  "folders.0" : { 
    $elemMatch: {
      $eq: "text"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I replicate this on Morphia? I am having trouble with the query  $elemMatch: { $eq: "text" }.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to the following (adapt the class name first):

```
datastore.createQuery(<yourClassName>.class).filter("folders.0 elem", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$eq", "text").get())
```

In the above the "elem" part of the string is an operator as you can see yourself in the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/guides/querying/)

[BasicDBObjectBuilder](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObjectBuilder.html) is a MongoDB package utility class. It will help you building objects that might be used with morphia too.